# How to draw a rectangle in Java?

Tags: java, swing, geometry, graphics2d

I am working on an application that needs to draw shapes (rectangle etc) by searching an array like:

```
while(array!=null)
{
    if(array.equals("x"))
    then 
    drawRect(100,100,50,20);
}
```

Every rectangle must be drawn on a single Frame and with different coordinates.

Comment: the word `then` isn't exist in java

Comment: You need to specify which element of the array you are accessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your code. The word `then` doesn't exist in Java.

```
while(array!=null) {
    if(array.equals("x")) {
         drawRect(100,100,50,20);
    }
}
```

There are so many example in Google. The best of all is [Drawing Geometric Primitives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html) by Oracle Tutorials.

```
public void paint (Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    if (yourCondition) {
        g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, rectwidth, rectheight));
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
// Define an array
String[] array = {"a","b","x"};

for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if(array[i] == "x")
    {
        drawRect(100,100,50,20);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `.equals`, not `==` to compare `String`s in Java.